# Reg file for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I've been trying to update Far Cry 3, which I purchased via Steam, but I keep getting an error. I googled for a solution and I came upon several posts on different forums saying that updating the registry with 5 keys that the game is looking for before updating should fix the problem. So I created a reg file exactly as instructed, but it does not seem to work. I'm getting this error: "the specified file is not a registry script. You can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor."

Here's the content of the reg file. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3]
"InstallDir"="D:\\Games\\SteamLibrary\\SteamApps\\common\\Far Cry 3"
"SKU"="WW"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3\GameUpdate]
"InstallDir"="D:\\Games\\SteamLibrary\\SteamApps\\common\\Far Cry 3"
"info"="ca32d7a363334a55b66633237b0335b7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{E3B9C5A9-BD7A-4B56-B754-FAEA7DD6FA88}]
"DisplayVersion"="1.01"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not how a registry file is made. (Taken from [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/167579/how-to-make-your-own-windows-registry-hacks/))
First, open your `.reg` file with Notepad (or your favorite text editor) and put

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
```

as the first line. Then you can add the keys:

```
"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3] "InstallDir"="D:\Games\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Far Cry 3" "SKU"="WW"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3\GameUpdate] "InstallDir"="D:\Games\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Far Cry 3" "info"="ca32d7a363334a55b66633237b0335b7"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{E3B9C5A9-BD7A-4B56-B754-FAEA7DD6FA88}] "DisplayVersion"="1.01"
```

So in the end, the `.reg` file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3] "InstallDir"="D:\Games\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Far Cry 3" "SKU"="WW"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ubisoft\Far Cry 3\GameUpdate] "InstallDir"="D:\Games\SteamLibrary\SteamApps\common\Far Cry 3" "info"="ca32d7a363334a55b66633237b0335b7"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{E3B9C5A9-BD7A-4B56-B754-FAEA7DD6FA88}] "DisplayVersion"="1.01"
```